# iOS developer mode differences

Tags: ios

I want to use network link conditioning to slow my bandwidth consumption when streaming msnbc on my iPhone.  I'm wondering what differences occur on my phone when it's in developer mode.  Other than the fact that there are additional settings available, does the act of just putting it into developer mode affect any of its operations?  Basically, is there any down side to putting it into developer mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, enabling the hidden Developer settings by connecting to Xcode doesn't change anything on your device.  The default for all of the settings is "off," in which case your device will behave identically as one where the settings are still hidden.